# JS dialog box button changes size, unsually small

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery 1.8.3 and I noticed that in my dialog box, When users click on the select button (I change the button text to Apply and display new divs within the dialog box) and when the button text is Apply, the button size becomes unusually small.

Any ideas?

```
ErrorCodeDialog = $("#treeview").dialog(
{ 
    closeOnEscape: true, 
    stack: false, 
    autoOpen: true, 
    modal: true, 
    resizable: false, 
    draggable: true, 
    title: 'Select and input Error details', 
    width: 480, 
    height: 500,

    buttons: 
    { 
        Select: function () 
        {
            var btnText = '';
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane :button').each(function () 
            {
                if ($(this).text() == 'Select') 
                {
                    btnText = 'Select';
                    $(this).text('Apply');
                    $("#errorCodes").attr("style", "display:none;");
                    $("#inputReps").attr("style", "display:inline;");
                }
                else if ($(this).text() == 'Apply') 
                {
                    btnText = 'Apply';
                    $(this).text('Select');
                    $("#errorCodes").attr("style", "display:inline;");
                    $("#inputReps").attr("style", "display:none;");
                }
            });
```

Comment: just a tipp: use a switch, makes the code much more easier to read.

Comment: what's in your css for that button?

Comment: He means a `switch` statement.

Comment: @RachelGallen I have not over-ridden any of my own styles for this button. It utilizes the jquery.ui.dialog.css version 1.8.11